# How to provide full path in require in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Trying to have access to functions from another file. Placed `(provide (all-defined-out))` inside the other file. Now trying to actually refer to it using full path:

```
(require “C:\Users\functions.rkt”)
```

returns this error: #%require: bad require spec in: “C:Usersfunctions.rkt”

```
(require "C:\Users\functions.rkt")
```

returns this error: read-syntax: no hex digit following `\U`

Comment: Try using a double-backslash ``\\`` to represent a single backslash character in a string

Answer (score 2):

There are two syntax errors in this snippet:

```
(require “C:\Users\functions.rkt”)
```

For starters, the double quote characters are incorrect. And you must escape the backslashes, and as Ryan points using `file` is mandatory. Try this:

```
(require (file "C:\\Users\\functions.rkt"))
```

Comment: why do slashes inside quotes have to be escaped?

Comment: A backslash is a escape character, and it gives a special meaning to anything that's after it. Example: "\n" is a new line character. But if you want to put a backslash just for the sake of it, with no special meaning attached to the character that follows it, then you have to escape it as well! And what's the escape character for a backslash? another backslash.

Comment: This is not specific to Racket, you'll find the same behavior for strings in most programming languages I can think of

Comment: You must use `file` with absolute paths. So it should be `(require (file "C:\\Users\\functions.rkt"))`.